# Connection leak from KafkaProducer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are trying to achieve java KafkaProducer resiliency where in case Kafka is not reachable for some reason then we are storing failed messages in files and retrying once kafka comes up. But we are checking periodically to see if kafka is available are not by trying to creating KafkaProducer object every 1 mins we observed that Too many files open issue is coming up. Where when we observed there are sockets getting open which are closing though we call Producer close function. Since this process runs as a daemon, how to release the sockets from Producer so that we dont get into this issue.

We get the log message

```
[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread] (kafka-admin-client-thread | consumer-id7035)
Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-admin-client-thread | consumer-id7035'
```

each time the kafkaproducer object is created. I need help in figuring out how to close cleanly when we keep trying to create new KafkaProducer objects to attemp resending of messages when kakfa is down

I tried using AdminClient to see if kafka is available or not, but even that caused the same isssue.

If Producer not able to connect to kafka it should comeout cleanly without holding sockets or any resources that it could have held.

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using? It would be great to check which exception escapes and leads to the log you are seeing.

Comment: kafka 2.1.1, we get IllegalstateException while sending data,hence we try reinitialize the kafkaproducer object, which is causing the connecion leak.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace?

Comment: ProducerRecord<K, V> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, payLoad);
        PublisherCallback publisherCallback = new PublisherCallback<V>(topic, payLoad, reProcessingPath,maxDiskSizeMB, lock);
        try {
            producer.send(record, publisherCallback);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            publisherCallback.cretaeJsonForFailedMessages();
            producer=new KafkaProducer<K, V>(props);
            throw e;
        }

Comment: above code runs in a loop, where it keeps trying, i will get the exception stacktrace shortly

Comment: 1234:publisher failed to publish data: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.throwIfProducerClosed(KafkaProducer.java:847)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:856)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:840)

Comment: since kafka connection failed this says producer closed, but still not releasing the resources that it holds.

Comment: watch "(date;lsof -p 17026|grep 'pipe\|socket'|wc -l)|tee -a log" output of this command shows that the pipes and sockets are increasing all the time till reaches  too many open files issue.

Comment: Sat Aug  3 00:07:48 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:07:50 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:07:52 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:07:54 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:07:56 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:07:59 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:08:01 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:08:03 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:08:05 PDT 2019
250
Sat Aug  3 00:08:07 PDT 2019
253
Sat Aug  3 00:08:09 PDT 2019
253
Sat Aug  3 00:08:12 PDT 2019
253
Sat Aug  3 00:08:14 PDT 2019
253
Sat Aug  3 00:08:16 PDT 2019
253

Comment: hello, please help